# Is it possible to instantiate an instance of class, passed as parameter to generic trait in Scala?

Tags: scala, reflection, traits, scala-2.10

I have the following code, written in Scala 2.10.0:

```
trait A[T <: B] {
  self : { def foo() } =>

  val action : ()=>Unit = this.foo _
  //wanna make default for this
  val construction : String=>T

  def bar()(implicit x : String) : T = {
    action()
    val destination = construction(x)
    destination.baz()
    destination
  }
}

trait B { def baz() {} }

class Xlass { def foo() {} }

class Klass(a : String)(implicit val x : String) extends B {
    val f = new Xlass with A[Klass] {
        //boilerplate!
        val construction = new Klass(_)
    }
}

implicit val x = "Something"
val destination = new Klass("some a").f.bar()
```

I wonder, is it possible to make a default for `construction`, such as `val construction = new T(_)`? 
I've tried several options for now, but none of them works with all the characteristics of this code, such as use of type bounds, implicits and structural typing. As far as I could get is this, but it fails with `scala.ScalaReflectionException: free type T is not a class`:

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._
val tT = weakTypeTag[T]
...
val privConstruction = 
  x : String => 
    runtimeMirror(tT.mirror.getClass.getClassLoader)
    //fails here with scala.ScalaReflectionException: free type T is not a class 
    .reflectClass(tT.tpe.typeSymbol.asClass) 
    .reflectConstructor(tT.tpe.members.head.asMethod)(x).asInstanceOf[T]
```

Comment: What is tT? Please provide a full snippet.

Comment: T here is just a type parameter, which Scala doesn't know anything about. That's what reflectClass is hinting at. To propagate info about T from call sites to callees, you need to annotate T with the TypeTag or WeakTypeTag context bound, like in `class C[T: TypeTag]`. Unfortunately, context bounds aren't supported for traits, so you'll have to work around.

Comment: @EugeneBurmako But weakTypeTag[T] inside trait A is equivalent to context bound, isn't it?

Comment: weakTypeTag[T] is the receiving end, which simply gets an implicit value of type WeakTypeTag[T]: https://github.com/scalamacros/kepler/blob/b4be0886d1d1561538102d973d1fd34bc3eef5cb/src/reflect/scala/reflect/api/TypeTags.scala#L350. For it to work you need to declare that implicit value somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, finally, I did it:

```scala
trait A[T <: B] {
  self : { def foo() } =>

  val action : ()=>Unit = this.foo _
  def construction(x: String)(implicit tag : reflect.ClassTag[T]) : T = {
    tag.runtimeClass.getConstructor(classOf[String], classOf[String]).newInstance(x, x).asInstanceOf[T]
  }

  def bar()(implicit x : String, tag : reflect.ClassTag[T]) : T = {
    action()
    val destination = construction(x)
    destination.baz()
    destination
  }
}

trait B { def baz() {} }

class Xlass { def foo() {} }

class Klass(a : String)(implicit val x : String) extends B {
    val f = new Xlass with A[Klass]
}

implicit val x = "Something"
val destination = new Klass("some a").f.bar()
```